# Problema con diccionarios y for

Tags: python

estaba haciendo un ejercicio en el cual tenía que crear un programa que cuente el número de veces que aparece una palabra en una string y realicé el siguiente código:

```
palabras_veces = dict()
veces_aparece = 0
string_usuario = input("Dime una frase: ")

for palabra in string_usuario:
    veces_aparece += 1
    str(veces_aparece)
    palabras_veces[palabra] = veces_aparece
    veces_aparece = 0

print(palabras_veces)
```

El problema es que el output no es el que espero:

```
Dime una frase: Hola amigos amigos Hola
{'H': 1, 'o': 1, 'l': 1, 'a': 1, ' ': 1, 'm': 1, 'i': 1, 'g': 1, 's': 1}
```

Se que debe ser una tonteria pero estoy un poco estancado, gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que sucede es que al recorrer la frase con el for estas accediendo a cada letra, es por eso que te aparece cada letra con su respectiva cantidad. Otra cosa ¿que buscas en realidad? ¿Que cuente cuantas veces aparece cada palabra o alguna palabra que se repita?

Comment: Que el programa me diga cuantas veces se repita una palabra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El bucle que hiciste, esta iterando letra a letra, para poder iterar por palabra, debes usar `split()`. De esa manera tendrás una `lista` de "palabras" separadas por un `espacio`.
Una posibilidad podría ser utilizar `count()` que devuelve la cantidad de apariciones de subcadena dentro de cadena. Vamos a convertir la cadena introducida por el usuario a mayúsculas,iteramos, contamos y mostramos:

```
palabras_veces = dict()

string_usuario = input("Dime una frase: ").upper().split()


for palabra in string_usuario:
    palabras_veces[palabra] = string_usuario.count(palabra)

print(palabras_veces)
```

Dime una frase: `Hola amigos amigos Hola`

```
{'HOLA': 2, 'AMIGOS': 2}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuestas amigo, no sabía que existían esas funciones, es que el profesor del curso no las había dicho jajaja. Una duda, es necesario convertir la cadena a mayúsculas o es solo por estética?

Comment: Probablemente la clase siguiente la enseñará. Convertir la cadena a mayúsculas o minúsculas es porque a veces puede estar una palabra más de una 1 vez.  `ej : "Esta oración contiene esta palabra" `. Sí no lo convertimos a mayús/minús , el resultado sería distinto.